# ¿Cómo estructurar una tabla de MySQL para registrar distintos productos?

Tags: php

Tengo que crear una página de comercio electrónico y no sé como diseñar la base de datos específicamente en la parte de los productos , ya que si un producto es , por ejemplo : Laptop tendría características como Sistema operativo , memoria , disco duro , etc . pero también quiero incluir productos como por ejemplo : cámaras , que tendrían características como : modelo , resolución , zoom , etc.

Debido a estas diferencias de características no sé como crear una estructura genérica para almacenar estos diferentes tipos de productos, la razón de hacer esto es para incluir las especificaciones técnicas de cada producto en la web , agradecería cualquier comentario , ayuda o recomendación al respecto .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es uno de los grandes desafíos de las bases de datos relacionales. La respuesta rápida es que, desde un punto de vista formal, si las cámaras y las laptops no tienen los mismos campos, entonces no deberían estar en la misma tabla.

Por supuesto, todos nos topamos con situaciones similares a la tuya, así que a lo largo del tiempo se desarrollaron soluciones muy robustas. La más correcta se llama [Sixth normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form) y es un desafío de implementación incluso para ingenieros en sistemas con larga experiencia en SQL, pero podemos simplificarla torciendo un poco la definición de "relación trivial entre campos".

La teoría es que uno tiene una tabla **productos**:

```
id, nombre, precio
```

Y una tabla auxiliar para cada tipo de producto, con una llave foránea que apunta a la tabla **productos**, por ejemplo, **productos_laptops**, con una estructura como:

```
id, id_producto, disco_rigido, ram, sistema_operativo
```

Y **productos_camaras**, con una estructura como:

```
id, id_producto, resolucion, zoom, capacidad
```

La versión simple de 6NF simplificado se llama [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), y es más fácil de implementar, pero te puede traer problemas dependiendo de la forma en que quieras manipular la información en la tabla. Esta solución implica crear una tabla secundaria **campos_secundarios** con una llave foránea que apunte a la tabla **productos**, y una estructura como:

```
id, id_producto, campo, valor
```

Con datos como:

```
1, 1, "Memoria RAM", "32 GB"
2, 1, "Disco rígido", "2 TB"
3, 1, "Sistema operativo", "Windows 10"
4, 2, "Resolución", "19 MP"
5, 2, "Zoom", "16x"
6, 2, "Capacidad", "512 GB"
```

Por último, la solución rápida y furiosa es guardar todos los campos secundarios en un objeto JSON en una columna de tipo TEXT, y al momento de filtrar los productos, usar una sintaxis horriblemente ineficiente como:

```
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE campos_secundarios_json LIKE '%"Memoria RAM":"32 GB"%';
```

Esto es una aberración desde todo punto de vista, pero para armar una página demo cuyo código nadie va a leer jamás, te puede sacar de un apuro.

Comment: Gracias Leandro , una consulta sobre tu último comentario , yo pienso guardar los datos con el modelo EAV que comentaste , pero también quiero hacer una búsqueda general de productos en la página , y mi idea principal era que funcione con un query muy parecido al que describiste como una aberración :( , me gustaría aprender sobre métodos más eficientes de como hacer eso , tendrás alguna recomendación o un buen post que conozcas con dicha información ?

Comment: EAV es algo que se sufre; no que se elige. No hay una forma perfecta de implementarlo, porque las bases de datos relacionales no están pensadas para hacer lo que vos necesitás. Lo formalmente correcto es implementar un paradigma distinto, como MongoDB, pero si estás limitado a MySQL, hacete la idea de que estás armando un hack, y apuntá a lograr algo que no te traiga demasiados dolores de cabeza y que se ajuste a los requerimientos del proyecto. No necesitás reinventar la rueda por un sitio con 100 productos y 1.000 visitas mensuales. Leé los primeros resultados de "eav mysql tutorial".

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas dos tablas: **productos** que sería la tabla maestra y **caracteristicas_producto** que sería el detalle.

En **caracteristicas_productos** creas una llave foránea a la tabla **productos** y así insertas las características de esta forma:

```
codigo_producto      caracteristica        detalle
    1                sistema operativo     windows 10
    1                 memoria RAM          4GB
    2                 resolucion           13MP
```